# Сравнение массивов строк в C

Tags: c

Программа должна обрабатывать входные строки и выводить исходный текст. Когда же будет введена строка "DA!", то ввод должен прекратиться, но на этапе сравнения строк string и end программа видит их как разные строки и не завершается. Что не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



void readText (char *text)
{
    int howFive = 0;
    int numOfSym = 0;
    int numOfStr = 0;
    int allSym = 0;
    char symbol;
    char *string = NULL;
    char end[] = "DA!";
    while(1)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            symbol = getchar();

            if (symbol == '\t' || (numOfSym == 0) && (symbol == ' '))
            {
               continue;
            }
            if (symbol == '5'){
                howFive++;
            }
            else 
            {
                howFive = 0;
            }
            if (howFive == 3)
            {
                string = NULL;
                break;
            }

            numOfSym++;
            string = (char*)realloc(string, numOfSym*sizeof(string));
            string[numOfSym - 1] = symbol;

            if (symbol == ';' || symbol == '.' || symbol == '?' || symbol == '!')
            {
                numOfSym++;
                string = (char*)realloc(string, numOfSym*sizeof(string));
                string[numOfSym - 1] = '\n';
                break;
            }
        }

        if (string == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", "строка удалена");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            numOfStr++;
            printf("%d ", numOfStr);
            allSym += numOfSym;
            printf("%d\n", allSym); // del
            text = (char*)realloc(text, (allSym)*sizeof(text));
            strcat(text, string);
            printf("%s", text); // del
            if (strcmp(string, end) == 0) 
            {
                printf("OK\n");  //del
                break;
            }
            string = NULL;
            numOfSym = 0; 
        }

    }       
    printf("%s", text);    


}


int main(){
   char *text = NULL;
   readText(text);

}
```

Comment: `if (3 == strlen(instr)) { if (instr[0] == 'D' && instr[1] == 'A' && instr[2] == '!') return; }` например так

Comment: В вашем коде очень много странного, например для `NULL` `realloc`, потом `(char*)realloc(text, (allSym)*sizeof(string))`? там всегда будет в 4 а то и в 8 раз больше необходимой памяти.

Comment: Это если строка маленькая, но в реальном задании у меня строка состоящая из большего количества символов.

Comment: Выделение памяти под строку регулируется формулой: `strlen(inputstring) + 1` Есть ещё функция `strdup(inputstring)` она это сделает за вас.

Comment: Я благодарен за указания на мои недочеты в коде, но это не решает мою проблему. Так же хотел добавить, что могу пользоваться только стандартными библиотеками С.

Comment: Вы бы лучше объяснили словами, какой алгоритм получения строки, которая должна быть добавлена к `text` (и следовательно с которой вы выполняете `strcmp(string, end` вы пытаетесь запрограммировать.

Comment: В принципе, я вижу, что перед `break` из внутреннего цикла (что приводит к `strcmp(string, end)` вы добавляете к `string` `'\n'`, а строка `end = "DA!"`  `'\n'` не содержит. Это формально объясняет вашу ошибку, но все остальное доверия не вызывает...

Comment: Алгоритм: 1) Удалить пробел вначале, если есть. 2) Удалить табуляцию в строке. 3) Не записывать строку, если в ней есть "555". 4) Концом строки является символы '.', ';', '?' (конец последней строки всегда заканчивается '!'). 5) Записать все строки с новой строки.

Comment: Спасибо, avp. Это помогло

Comment: @LLENN: В `realloc` для null-указателя нет ничего странного.

Comment: Вообще-то у вас будут лишние `\n` в начале следующей строки, если после конца строки (`.!?;`) пользователь вводит ENTER   (или это так и задумано?). В любом случае надо бы вызывать `free(string)` перед `string = NULL;` и уберите умножение на размер указателя в `realloc`

Comment: Между прочим, `strcat` в данном случае это ошибка (вы же не завершаете `text` нулем). Вместо нее можно вызвать `memcpy(text + allSym - numOfSym, string, numOfSym);`. А в конце накопления всего текста лучше будет все же завершить `text` нулем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main() {
  char *text = calloc(1,1), buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin))
  {
    size_t sz = strlen(buffer);
    if (3 == sz) { if (buffer[0] == 'D' && buffer[1] == 'A' && buffer[2] == '!') break; }
    text = realloc( text, strlen(text)+1+sz);
    strcat( text, buffer );
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
  }
  printf("\n\nText:\n%s",text);
  return 0;
}
```

Попробуйте так